# Mounted Volume appeared in nautilus

Tags: mount, nautilus, directory

I am seriously confused. I don't know if I installed something, or an update got me this, or where this behaviour is coming from, but I want to understand it and as well I want to understand how to control it.

Today I suddenly noticed a mounted Volume in my OS:

[image]

$ tree -L 3
.

```
├── bin
│   └── telegram-desktop
├── data-dir
│   └── kf5
├── etc
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── conf.avail
│   │   ├── conf.d
│   │   └── fonts.conf
│   ├── gss
│   │   └── mech.d
│   ├── gtk-3.0
│   │   ├── im-multipress.conf
│   │   └── settings.ini
│   ├── mailcap.order
│   ├── mime.types
│   ├── pulse
│   │   └── client.conf
│   ├── python3.6
│   │   └── sitecustomize.py
│   ├── ucf.conf
│   ├── vdpau_wrapper.cfg
│   └── X11
│       └── xkb
├── lib
│   ├── bindtextdomain.so
│   ├── libdbusmenu-qt5.so -> libdbusmenu-qt5.so.2
│   ├── libdbusmenu-qt5.so.2 -> libdbusmenu-qt5.so.2.6.0
│   ├── libdbusmenu-qt5.so.2.6.0
│   ├── libopenal.so -> libopenal.so.1
│   ├── libopenal.so.1 -> libopenal.so.1.20.1
│   ├── libopenal.so.1.20.1
│   ├── libxxhash.a
│   ├── libxxhash.so -> libxxhash.so.0.7.2
│   ├── libxxhash.so.0 -> libxxhash.so.0.7.2
│   ├── libxxhash.so.0.7.2
│   └── x86_64-linux-gnu
│       ├── libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.8.7
│       ├── libbsd.so.0.8.7
│       ├── libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
│       ├── libcom_err.so.2.1
│       ├── libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.19.4
│       ├── libdbus-1.so.3.19.4
│       ├── libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.7
│       ├── libexpat.so.1.6.7
│       ├── libhistory.so.7 -> libhistory.so.7.0
│       ├── libhistory.so.7.0
│       ├── libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5
│       ├── libkeyutils.so.1.5
│       ├── liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.2.2
│       ├── liblzma.so.5.2.2
│       ├── libreadline.so.7 -> libreadline.so.7.0
│       ├── libreadline.so.7.0
│       ├── libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
│       ├── libwrap.so.0.7.6
│       ├── libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
│       └── libz.so.1.2.11
├── meta
│   ├── gui
│   │   ├── icon.png
│   │   └── telegram-desktop.desktop
│   └── snap.yaml
├── share
│   ├── applications
│   │   └── telegramdesktop.desktop
│   ├── icons
│   │   └── hicolor
│   ├── metainfo
│   │   └── telegramdesktop.appdata.xml
│   └── openal
│       ├── hrtf
│       └── presets
├── snap
│   ├── command-chain
│   │   ├── desktop-launch
│   │   ├── locale-gen
│   │   └── snapcraft-runner
│   ├── kde-frameworks-5-core18-sdk
│   ├── manifest.yaml
│   └── snapcraft.yaml
├── usr
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── cautious-launcher
│   │   ├── compose -> run-mailcap
│   │   ├── edit -> run-mailcap
│   │   ├── fc-cache
│   │   ├── fc-cat
│   │   ├── fc-list
│   │   ├── fc-match
│   │   ├── fc-pattern
│   │   ├── fc-query
│   │   ├── fc-scan
│   │   ├── fc-validate
│   │   ├── gtk-update-icon-cache
│   │   ├── lcf
│   │   ├── pdb3 -> pdb3.6
│   │   ├── pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py
│   │   ├── print -> run-mailcap
│   │   ├── py3clean
│   │   ├── py3compile
│   │   ├── py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
│   │   ├── pydoc3 -> pydoc3.6
│   │   ├── pydoc3.6
│   │   ├── pygettext3 -> pygettext3.6
│   │   ├── pygettext3.6
│   │   ├── python3 -> python3.6
│   │   ├── python3.6
│   │   ├── python3.6m
│   │   ├── python3m -> python3.6m
│   │   ├── run-mailcap
│   │   ├── see -> run-mailcap
│   │   ├── ucf
│   │   ├── ucfq
│   │   ├── ucfr
│   │   └── update-mime-database
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── dconf
│   │   ├── glib-networking
│   │   ├── libavcodec.so -> libavcodec.so.58.54.100
│   │   ├── libavcodec.so.58 -> libavcodec.so.58.54.100
│   │   ├── libavcodec.so.58.54.100
│   │   ├── libavdevice.so -> libavdevice.so.58.8.100
│   │   ├── libavdevice.so.58 -> libavdevice.so.58.8.100
│   │   ├── libavdevice.so.58.8.100
│   │   ├── libavfilter.so -> libavfilter.so.7.57.100
│   │   ├── libavfilter.so.7 -> libavfilter.so.7.57.100
│   │   ├── libavfilter.so.7.57.100
│   │   ├── libavformat.so -> libavformat.so.58.29.100
│   │   ├── libavformat.so.58 -> libavformat.so.58.29.100
│   │   ├── libavformat.so.58.29.100
│   │   ├── libavutil.so -> libavutil.so.56.31.100
│   │   ├── libavutil.so.56 -> libavutil.so.56.31.100
│   │   ├── libavutil.so.56.31.100
│   │   ├── libswresample.so -> libswresample.so.3.5.100
│   │   ├── libswresample.so.3 -> libswresample.so.3.5.100
│   │   ├── libswresample.so.3.5.100
│   │   ├── libswscale.so -> libswscale.so.5.5.100
│   │   ├── libswscale.so.5 -> libswscale.so.5.5.100
│   │   ├── libswscale.so.5.5.100
│   │   ├── mime
│   │   ├── python3
│   │   ├── python3.6
│   │   ├── systemd
│   │   ├── valgrind
│   │   └── x86_64-linux-gnu
│   ├── sbin
│   │   ├── update-icon-caches
│   │   └── update-mime
│   └── share
│       ├── alsa
│       ├── applications
│       ├── apport
│       ├── binfmts
│       ├── bug
│       ├── cinnamon
│       ├── dbus-1
│       ├── doc
│       ├── doc-base
│       ├── ffmpeg
│       ├── fonts
│       ├── GConf
│       ├── glib-2.0
│       ├── icons
│       ├── libdrm
│       ├── libthai
│       ├── lintian
│       ├── locale
│       ├── man
│       ├── mime
│       ├── pixmaps
│       ├── pkgconfig
│       ├── python3
│       ├── themes
│       ├── thumbnailers
│       ├── X11
│       └── xml
└── var
    └── lib
        └── ucf
```

Can anyone explain me, what this is? Guess I think it's telegram, but why does it suddenly appear this way? Is that normal behaviour?

Any hints and Buzzwords so that I can understand the topic are welcome.

Linux 4.15.0-58-generic #64~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thank you

Comment: Did you install telegram?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes, a while ago, but there never was that Volume, after unmounting and restart it is also not mounted again. I do not unerstand the process happening there.

Comment: I am thinking a glitch on the part of telegram installer!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thank you. I also guess it must have been an update. But I also don't understand why to process takes place this way. Making a volume for updates? What kind of software architecture style is this?